# .NET's Multi-threading vs Multi-processing: Awful Parallel.ForEach Performance

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, multiprocessing

I have coded a very simple "Word Count" program that reads a file and counts each word's occurrence in the file. Here is a part of the code:

```
class Alaki
{
    private static List<string> input = new List<string>();

    private static void exec(int threadcount)
    {
        ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
        options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threadcount;
        Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, input.Count),options, (range) =>
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
            for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
            {
                //make some delay!
                //for (int x = 0; x < 400000; x++) ;                    

                var tokens = input[i].Split();
                foreach (var token in tokens)
                {
                    if (!dic.ContainsKey(token))
                        dic[token] = new List<int>();
                    dic[token].Add(1);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {            
        StreamReader reader=new StreamReader((@"c:\txt-set\agg.txt"));
        while(true)
        {
            var line=reader.ReadLine();
            if(line==null)
                break;
            input.Add(line);
        }

        DateTime t0 = DateTime.Now;
        exec(Environment.ProcessorCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Parallel:  " + (DateTime.Now - t0));
        t0 = DateTime.Now;
        exec(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Serial:  " + (DateTime.Now - t0));
    }
}
```

It is simple and straight forward. I use a dictionary to count each word's occurrence. The style is roughly based on the [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) programming model. As you can see, each task is using its own private dictionary. So, there is NO shared variables; just a bunch of tasks that count words by themselves. Here is the output when the code is run on a quad-core i7 CPU:

Parallel:  00:00:01.6220927
Serial:  00:00:02.0471171

The speedup is about 1.25 which means a tragedy! But when I add some delay when processing each line, I can reach speedup values about 4.

In the original parallel execution with no delay, CPU's utilization hardly reaches to 30% and therefore the speedup is not promising. But, when we add some delay, CPU's utilization reaches to 97%.

Firstly, I thought the cause is the IO-bound nature of the program (but I think inserting into a dictionary is to some extent CPU intensive) and it seems logical because all of the threads are reading data from a shared memory bus. However, The surprising point is when I run 4 instances of serial programs (with no delays) simultaneously, CPU's utilization reaches to about raises and all of the four instances finish in about 2.3 seconds!

This means that when the code is being run in a multiprocessing configuration, it reaches to a speedup value about 3.5 but when it is being run in multithreading config, the speedup is about 1.25.

What is your idea?
Is there anything wrong about my code? Because I think there is no shared data at all and I think the code shall not experience any contentions.
Is there a flaw in .NET's run-time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can download a 6 MB text file from: [http://norvig.com/big.txt](http://norvig.com/big.txt)

Comment: First Clue: create a ReadOnlyCollection based on input List and use it inside your delegate

Comment: You realize that your chosen method of adding a delay will tend to increase the apparent CPU utilization?  Have you use Resource Monitor to get a feel for the CPU, I/O and memory utilization?

Comment: @HABO I use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). But as I said, running multiple processes give a much better result!

Comment: Environment.ProcessorCount will get you the number of virtual processors in the system, that may not be the number of processors available to your process.

Comment: @Science_Fiction I know! But if I set the number of threads to 4, there is no change. I have tested that.

Comment: How big is your text file? The work may not be big enough to justify the partitioning

Comment: @Rotem I have tested with different sizes for 1 MB to 100 MB. However the result is the same!

Comment: @Jani tested with the AsReadOnly() method but it has no effect!

Comment: Have you tested using files in which all lines are of generally similar length? In the sample you posted, some lines are 50 words long while others are 0 or 1 words long. This might cause the thread that got the biggest job to be a bottleneck.

Comment: @Rotem I tried splitting the lines with 50 words as you said but no success!

Comment: @Rotem: The default partitioner for `Parallel.For` tries to divide work intelligently to avoid this problem; see http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/26/parallelism-in-net-part-5-partitioning-of-work/ for details.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`Parallel.For` doesn't divide the input into *n* pieces (where *n* is the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`); instead it creates many small batches and makes sure that at most *n* are being processed concurrently. (This is so that if one batch takes a very long time to process, `Parallel.For` can still be running work on other threads. See [Parallelism in .NET - Part 5, Partioning of Work](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/26/parallelism-in-net-part-5-partitioning-of-work/) for more details.)

Due to this design, your code is creating and throwing away dozens of Dictionary objects, hundreds of List objects, and thousands of String objects. This is putting enormous pressure on the garbage collector.

Running [PerfMonitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2010/08/02/perfmonitor-runanalyze-a-quick-performance-checkup-for-your-managed-app.aspx) on my computer reports that 43% of the total run time is spent in GC. If you rewrite your code to use fewer temporary objects, you should see the desired 4x speedup. Some excerpts from the PerfMonitor report follow:

> Over 10% of the total CPU time was spent in the garbage collector.
> Most well tuned applications are in the 0-10% range. This is typically
> caused by an allocation pattern that allows objects to live just long
> enough to require an expensive Gen 2 collection.
>
> This program had a peak GC heap allocation rate of over 10 MB/sec.
> This is quite high. It is not uncommon that this is simply a
> performance bug.

**Edit:** As per your comment, I will attempt to explain the timings you reported. On my computer, with PerfMonitor, I measured between 43% and 52% of time spent in GC. For simplicity, let's assume that 50% of the CPU time is work, and 50% is GC. Thus, if we make the work 4× faster (through multi-threading) but keep the amount of GC the same (this will happen because the number of batches being processed happened to be the same in the parallel and serial configurations), the best improvement we could get is 62.5% of the original time, or 1.6×.

However, we only see a 1.25× speedup because GC isn't multithreaded by default (in workstation GC). As per [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx), all managed threads are paused during a Gen 0 or Gen 1 collection. (Concurrent and background GC, in .NET 4 and .NET 4.5, can collect Gen 2 on a background thread.) Your program experiences only a 1.25× speedup (and you see 30% CPU usage overall) because the threads spend most of their time being paused for GC (because the memory allocation pattern of this test program is very poor).

If you enable [server GC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357.aspx), it will perform garbage collection on multiple threads. If I do this, the program runs 2× faster (with almost 100% CPU usage).

When you run four instances of the program simultaneously, each has its own managed heap, and the garbage collection for the four processes can execute in parallel. This is why you see 100% CPU usage (each process is using 100% of one CPU). The slightly longer overall time (2.3s for all vs 2.05s for one) is possibly due to inaccuracies in measurement, contention for the disk, time taken to load the file, having to initialise the threadpool, overhead of context switching, or some other environment factor.

Comment: Your comments are valuable, specially the PerfMonitor tool seems to be very interesting. Thanks for the comments. But how can you explain the case of running 4 concurrent serial processes?

Comment: @SaeedShahrivari: I've updated my answer with details that I hope will address your timing questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is absolutely right. The problem lies in the garbage collector and using the server GC can help a lot. Now I shall see that whether a multi-threaded garbage collector is available or not? Thanks again.

Comment: @SaeedShahrivari - Before changing the GC, look at restructuring your code to use memory more efficiently.

Comment: @SaeedShahrivari: Even if you enable server GC, you may only get a 2× speedup (instead of the theoretical 4×); the real problem is that so much garbage is being created. .NET has an excellent GC, but the memory allocation pattern of this test code is "stress testing" it. Try reducing the amount of garbage being created by: reusing objects; preallocating capacity in `List<T>`; avoid `String.Split` (which creates temporary arrays); use a memory profiler to understand the allocation behaviour of the program.

Answer (score 9):

An attempt to explain the results:

- a quick run in the VS profiler shows it's barely reaching 40% CPU utilization.
- String.Split is the main hotspot.
- so a shared something must be blocking the the CPU.
- that something is most likely memory allocation. Your bottlenecks are

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
...
   dic[token].Add(1);
```

I replaced this with

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
...
... else dic[token] += 1;
```

and the result is closer to a 2x speedup.

But my counter question would be: does it matter? Your code is very artificial and incomplete. The parallel version ends up creating multiple dictionaries without merging them. This is not even close to a real situation. And as you can see, little details do matter.

Your sample code is to complex to make broad statements about `Parallel.ForEach()`.
It is too simple to solve/analyze a real problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My code is much more comprehensive but for better illumination I coded a sample toy example here. The string.split() point seems interesting I can use some tools like .NET Reflector to investigate it.

Comment: You need to profile this and see what's going on. If Garbage Collect is the hotspot, try turning on server GC.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is a shorter PLINQ version:

```
File.ReadAllText("big.txt").Split().AsParallel().GroupBy(t => t)
                                                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```