# Parallel.Invoke gives a minimal performance increase if any

Tags: c#, .net, performance, task-parallel-library

I wrote a simple console app to test the performance of Parallel.Invoke based on Microsoft's example on msdn:

```
public static void TestParallelInvokeSimple()
    {
        ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }; // 1 to disable threads, -1 to enable them
        Parallel.Invoke(parallelOptions,
            () =>
                {
                    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                    sw.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Begin first task...");
                    List<string> objects = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
                    {
                        if (objects.Count > 0)
                        {
                            string tempstr = string.Join("", objects.Last().Take(6).ToList());
                            objects.Add(tempstr + i);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objects.Add("START!");
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("End first task... {0} seconds", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                },
            () =>
                {
                    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                    sw.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Begin second task...");
                    List<string> objects = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
                    {
                        objects.Add("abc" + i);
                    }
                    sw.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("End second task... {0} seconds", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                },
            () =>
                {
                    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                    sw.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Begin third task...");
                    List<string> objects = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
                    {
                        objects.Add("abc" + i);
                    }
                    sw.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("End third task... {0} seconds", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                }
            );
    }
```

The ParallelOptions is to easily enable/disable threading.

When I disable threading I get the following output:

```
Begin first task...
End first task... 10.034647 seconds
Begin second task...
End second task... 3.5326487 seconds
Begin third task...
End third task... 6.8715266 seconds
done!
Total elapsed time: 20.4456563 seconds
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

When I enable threading by setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism to -1 I get:

```
Begin third task...
Begin first task...
Begin second task...
End second task... 5.9112167 seconds
End third task... 13.113622 seconds
End first task... 19.5815043 seconds
done!
Total elapsed time: 19.5884057 seconds
```

Which is practically the same speed as sequential processing.  Since task 1 takes the longest - about 10 seconds, I would expect the threading to take around 10 seconds total to run all 3 tasks.  So what gives?  ***Why is Parallel.Invoke running my tasks slower individually, yet in parallel?***

BTW, I've seen the exact same results when using Parallel.Invoke in a real app performing many different tasks at the same time (most of which are running queries).

If you think it's my pc, think again... it's 1 year old, with 8GB of RAM, windows 8.1, Intel Core I7 2.7GHz 8 core cpu.  My PC is not overloaded as I watched the performance while running my tests over and over again.  My PC never maxed out but obviously showed cpu and memory increase when running.

Comment: Strings are a "special" type. What happens if you play with some other data type?

Comment: You're doing a huge amount of memory allocations. In effect, your code isn't CPU-bound, but rather memory-and-GC-bound. Since the garbage collector in .NET will force all the threads to freeze before doing its thing, you've managed to bottle-neck your code to what a single thread will give you. And even apart from the GC, most of the work you're doing is allocations. That puts a lot of pressure on memory, and very little on the CPU. And memory access is slow, and very much non-paralelizable (in desktop PCs, that is).

Comment: @Luaan - You're right, it's the GC in combination with allocating lots of heap memory that are killing the performance.   I just found this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671053/nets-multi-threading-vs-multi-processing-awful-parallel-foreach-performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't profiled this, but the majority of the time here is probably being spent doing memory allocation for those lists and tiny strings. These "tasks" aren't actually doing anything other than growing the lists with minimal input and almost no processing time.

Consider that:

```
objects.Add("abc" + i);
```

is essentially just creating a new string and then adding it to a list.  Creating a small string like this is largely just a memory allocation exercise since strings are stored on the heap.  Furthermore, the memory allocated for the `List` is going to fill up rapidly - each time it does the list will re-allocate more memory for its own storage.

Now, heap allocations are serialized within a process - four threads inside one process cannot allocate memory at the same time.  Requests for memory allocation are processed in sequence since the shared heap is like any other shared resource that needs to be protected from concurrent mayhem.

So what you have are three extremely memory-hungry threads that are probably spending most of their time waiting for each other to finish getting new memory.

Fill those methods with CPU intensive work (ie : do some math, etc) and you'll see the results are very different.  The lesson is that not all tasks are efficiently parallelizable and not all in the ways that you might think.  The above, for example, could be sped up by running each task within its own process - with its own private memory space there would be no contention for memory allocation, for example.

Comment: "heap allocations are serialized within a process" - didn't know that!  This is exactly the problem.  I changed the code to use some functions in the Math library and not allocate any memory and now Parallel.Foreach behaves as expected.  Thanks for the good explanation.

Comment: @goku_da_master Note that there's a few different GCs in .NET (especially from .NET 4.5 on) - on a server OS, .NET may allocate separate heaps for different threads, which would parallelize allocations. Collections are still at least partially a blocking affair, though (although even there, some operations can be done multi-threaded, so more cores help somewhat).

Comment: @Luaan Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I just learned about gcserver, gcconcurrent and workstation server - all different garbage collectors.  gcserver uses multiple cores if available, and workstation only uses 1 core.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @goku_da_master Yeah, they are actually quite different. The basic idea is that the workstation GC is optimized for latency (so that the user isn't bothered by the interruptions), while the server GC is optimized for throughput. If you need server GC in a desktop application, your design could probably be improved to use better allocation and collection patterns. Of course, it doesn't matter much if your application isn't GUI-heavy.