# Parallel.Foreach just use 20-30% of CPU power

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have this Parallel.Foreach which just use 20-30% of CPU when I'm running it. 
forEach is:

```
Parallel.ForEach(activePointList,   new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, activePoints =>
                    {
    var nodesCPD = graph.NodesCPDIds.ToDictionary(d => d, d => new List<CostParentDestination>());
    var heap = new MinHeapGeneric<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
    foreach (var d in activePoints.Select(a => graph.OldNodes[new KeyValuePair<double, double>(a.XCoord, a.YCoord)]))
    {
        nodesCPD[d].Add(new CostParentDestination(0, -1, d, -1, 0));
        heap.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(d, 0), 0);
    }

    Calculate(graph.Nodes, nodesCPD, heap, graph.CalculationParams.MaxJourneyCost);
});
```

As you can see main function is Calculate which you can find its implementation here:

```
  public static void Calculate(
         Dictionary<int, MDDNode> nodes,
         Dictionary<int, List<CostParentDestination>> nodesCPD,
         MinHeapGeneric<KeyValuePair<int, int>> heap,
         int maxJourneyCost)
        {
            while (!heap.Empty())
            {
                var minItem = heap.PopMinItem();

                var currentNodeId = minItem.Key.Key;
                int cpdIndex = minItem.Key.Value;
                var cpd = nodesCPD[currentNodeId][cpdIndex];

                foreach (var edge in nodes[currentNodeId].Edges)
                {
                    var edgeId = edge.Key;
                    var activeCPD = nodesCPD[edgeId].FirstOrDefault(c => c.ParentId == currentNodeId);

                    if (activeCPD == null || activeCPD.Met || activeCPD.CostToNearestDestination <= cpd.CostToNearestDestination + edge.Value.Cost) continue;

                    int zcpdId = -1;
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < nodesCPD[edgeId].Count; idx++)
                        if (nodesCPD[edgeId][idx].ParentId == currentNodeId)
                            zcpdId = idx;

                    activeCPD.CostToNearestDestination = cpd.CostToNearestDestination + edge.Value.Cost;
                    activeCPD.DestinationId = cpd.DestinationId;
                    heap.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(edgeId, zcpdId), cpd.CostToNearestDestination + edge.Value.Cost);
                }
                cpd.Met = true;
            }           
        }
```

It reads min item and then iterate edges of that point, process continues until it sets distance of all points to destination.

this is implementation of Add and PopMinItem methods of heap, which I think is costly part of Calculate() method:

```
 public class MinHeapGeneric<T>
    {
        public Dictionary<int, T> KeyOfId = new Dictionary<int, T>();
        public Dictionary<T, int> IdOfKey = new Dictionary<T, int>();
        private readonly MinHeapLite _heap = new MinHeapLite();
        private int _id;

        public void Add(T key, double value)
        {
            int id;
            if (IdOfKey.ContainsKey(key))
                id = IdOfKey[key];
            else
            {
                id = _id++;
                KeyOfId.Add(id, key);
                IdOfKey.Add(key, id);
            }
            _heap.Add(new HeapItem(id, value));
        }

        public KeyValuePair<T, double> PopMinItem()
        {
            var item = _heap.PopMinItem();
            var key = KeyOfId[item.Id];
            IdOfKey.Remove(key);
            KeyOfId.Remove(item.Id);
            return new KeyValuePair<T, double>(key, item.Value);
        }
}

public class MinHeapLite
    {
        private readonly HeapItem[] _items;
        private readonly int _maxHeapSize;
        private int _lastItemIndex; //Items will start from 1. (root == 1)
        private readonly Dictionary<int, int> _idToIndexMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        public HeapItem PopMinItem()
        {
            if (Empty())
            {
                throw (new Exception("Popping from an empty Heap."));
            }
            HeapItem minItem = new HeapItem(_items[1]);

            HeapItem data = _items[_lastItemIndex];
            int parentIndex = 1;
            int childIndex = parentIndex * 2;
            while (childIndex < _lastItemIndex)
            {
                if (childIndex + 1 < _lastItemIndex && _items[childIndex].Value > _items[childIndex + 1].Value)
                    childIndex++;
                if (_items[childIndex].Value < data.Value)
                {
                    _items[parentIndex] = _items[childIndex];
                    _idToIndexMap[_items[parentIndex].Id] = parentIndex;
                    parentIndex = childIndex;
                    childIndex *= 2;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            _items[parentIndex] = data;
            _idToIndexMap[_items[parentIndex].Id] = parentIndex;
            _lastItemIndex--;
            _idToIndexMap.Remove(minItem.Id);
            return minItem;
        }
}
```

My question is that which part of code prevents main Foreach to use whole CPU power?

Comment: Have you tried to add `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };` on the Parallel.ForEach call ?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671053/nets-multi-threading-vs-multi-processing-awful-parallel-foreach-performance will be of interest for you.

Comment: @Sharped thanks for your prompt reply, I just added it, but doesn't have effect

Comment: _My question is that which part of code prevent main Foreach to use whole CPU power?_ You probably are missing an 's': It should read _which part of code prevents.._, right? -  `MaxDegreeOfParallelism ` is meant as a means to __reduce__ the number of cores used, which is not what you want, right? - The usual suspect: Is there any hidden IO in your code?

Comment: How many cores does your machine have?

Comment: Can you add indications about how many ActivePoints you have and the absolute running tiime?

Comment: @HenkHolterman around 1000 and it takes around one and half minutes

Comment: I think answer is 
[.NET's Multi-threading vs Multi-processing: Awful Parallel.ForEach Performance][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671053/nets-multi-threading-vs-multi-processing-awful-parallel-foreach-performance

Comment: Main problem here is amount of garbage collection. similar to this [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671053/nets-multi-threading-vs-multi-processing-awful-parallel-foreach-performance