# Why my code does not speed up with a multithreaded Parallel.For loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, thread-local

I tried to transform a simple sequential loop into a parallel computed loop with the `System.Threading.Tasks` library.
The code compiles, returns correct results, but It does not save any computational cost, otherwise, it takes longer.

---

EDIT: Sorry guys, I have probably oversimplified the question and made some errors doing that.
To append additional information, I am running the code on an i7-4700QM, and it is referenced in a [Grasshopper](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/) script. 
Here is the actual code. I also switched to a non thread-local variables

```
public static class LineNet
{        
    public static List<Ray> SolveCpu(List<Speaker> sources, List<Receiver> targets, List<Panel> surfaces)
    {
        ConcurrentBag<Ray> rays = new ConcurrentBag<Ray>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sources.Count; i++)
        {
            Parallel.For(
                0,
                targets.Count,
                j =>
                {
                    Line path = new Line(sources[i].Position, targets[j].Position);
                    Ray ray = new Ray(path, i, j);
                    if (Utils.CheckObstacles(ray,surfaces))
                    {
                        rays.Add(ray);
                    }

                }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

The Grasshopper implementation just collects `sources` `targets` and `surfaces`, calls the method `Solve` and returns `rays`.
I understand that dispatching workload to threads is expensive, but is it so expensive?
Or is the `ConcurrentBag` just preventing parallel calculation?

Plus, my classes are immutable (?), but if I use a common `List` the kernel aborts the operation and throws an exception, is someone able to tell why?

Comment: Parallel loops will generally only make your method run faster if the thing slowing your method down is the processor (ie - in a quad core computer, your CPU usage stays at 25% the whole time the method is running because the processor is working as hard as it can the whole time.)  If that's true, then spreading it out over multiple threads would help. If your method is waiting on the hard drive or on network resources or something else, it may not prove helpful. It is hard to say why this is slow without knowing more details about how you generate your `Lines` or what your program is doing...

Comment: How many lines are we talking about in your test? There's going to be some initial overhead so the benefit may not be immediately noticeable. Another thing is that `result.Add(line);` will block any threads also wanting to call the same line as your are using the `ConcurrentBag`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671629/22437) may be informative.

Comment: @ElementalPete I updated the question for a better explanation of the issue.
@TyCobb Hundreds of thousands of line. With 200 points in `sources` and 200 points in `targets`, it profiles 3.2s in Parallel mode, and 2.9s in sequental computing.
@DourHighArch a  really resourceful answer that helps investigate the problem

Answer (score 2):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it is not possible to provide a definitive answer. The code you posted does not even appear to be an excerpt of real code, because the type declared as the return type of the method isn't the same as the value actually returned by the `return` statement.

However, certainly the code you posted does not seem like a good use of `Parallel.For()`. Your `Line` constructor would have be fairly expensive to justify parallelizing the task of creating the items. And to be clear, that's the only possible win here.

At the end, you still need to aggregate all of the `Line` instances that you created into a single list, so all those intermediate lists created for the `Parallel.For()` tasks are just pure overhead. And the aggregation is necessarily serialized (i.e. only one thread at a time can be adding an item to the `result` collection), and in the worst way (each thread only gets to add a single item before it gives up the lock and another thread has a chance to take it).

Frankly, you'd be better off storing each local `List<T>` in a collection, and then aggregating them all at once in the main thread after `Parallel.For()` returns. Not that that would be likely to make the code perform better than a straight-up non-parallelized implementation. But at least it would be less likely to be worse. :)

The bottom line is that you don't seem to have a workload that could benefit from parallelization. If you think otherwise, you'll need to explain the basis for that thought in a clearer, more detailed way.

> if I use a common List the kernel aborts the operation and throws an exception, is someone able to tell why?

You're already using (it appears) `List<T>` as the local data for each task, and indeed that should be fine, as tasks don't share their local data.

But if you are asking why you get an exception if you try to use `List<T>` instead of `ConcurrentBag<T>` for the `result` variable, well that's entirely to be expected. The `List<T>` class is not thread safe, but `Parallel.For()` will allow each task it runs to execute the `localFinally` delegate concurrently with all the others. So you have multiple threads all trying to modify the same not-thread-safe collection concurrently. This is a recipe for disaster. You're fortunate you get the exception; the actual behavior is undefined, and it's just as likely you'll simply corrupt the data structure as cause a run-time exception.

Comment: I updated the question. To better explain why I am looking at parallel computation: I have two lists, both with hundreds of points; I want to connect each point in `List1` with each point in `List2`. Since this generates hundreds of thousands of line, I thought that if each line could have been an independent `Task`, and each task dispatched to different threads to split the workload, this would have sped things up. Now, I can see a non harmful read/read conflict in the Input lists, and a write/write conflict in the output list, which I thought was solved with the `ConcurrentBag`.

Comment: _"I thought was solved with the `ConcurrentBag`"_ -- depends on your definition of "solved". Using the thread-safe collection type ensures the data structure remains uncorrupt when used concurrently. But it also serializes all access to it, and because your synchronization granularity is once-per-element, there's potentially a lot of contention overhead. And, the cost of creating a single element is not high enough for all that overhead, in both the individual tasks and then at the final aggregation, to be worthwhile. All of which I've explained above.